# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<YYY> has no method 'xxx'

Tags: c#, javascript, extjs4, extjs

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Interact> has no method 'getmyData'
```

the problem is that it's true!

'Interact' has no method 'getmyData' it's 'myhandler' that contains it.

it's not supposed to go look for it in 'Interact' in first place but in 'myhandler' !

I have no clue why its acting like this because everything was working fine and suddenly i get this error!

Some code:

myHandler.ashx :

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="myHandler" %>
...
public class myHandler : JsonRpcHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

[JsonRpcMethod()]
public string getmyData()
{
.. 
}
```

i call it in my script:

```
var obj = new myHandler();
...
listeners: {
    selectionchange: function (model, records) {

        myStore.loadData(Ext.decode(obj.getmyData()));

        }
```

Let me know if u need more details!

Comment: It might be POST or GET issues. Check request type.

Comment: what request? there is no get or post here

Comment: so how do you load data? :) I supposed you send ajax request to your server code. For example your server handler i configured to accept only POST request, but you are sending GET. Check in Firebug, Net or Console tabs.

Comment: i load data with this function from extjs loadData() and get data from  server side function by calling getmyData()

Comment: yep, but your store is loading it for you with AJAX request.

Comment: yes `proxy: {
         type: 'rest',
         url: '',         
         reader: 'json'
     }, `

Comment: i dont do it myself so i dont know how to check, but i dont think this is where the problem come from, as i said it was working perfectly before and still work if i call it in somewhere else, its only when i call it inside my selectionchange that i have the problem..at least this what i think so far

Comment: Fiddler will help you troubleshoot ajax requests. ..and technically you *are* doing a post/get with your ajax, just sayin'

Comment: fiddler doesnt give me any error

Comment: try to add actionMethods: 'POST' to your proxy properties

Comment: Maybe you made a spelling error? there is an exception about getData and you have method called getmyData.

Comment: no my function name is not getmyData i just changed it because its a long maybe non understandable for u,tried to use a simpler one..first thing i checked is spelling , i dont think there is any error specially that it was working fine before and i havent change anything on that script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved
seems there was an interferance or something

all i had to do is change the name of my var:

```
var obj = new myHandler();
```

to something else like

```
var mh = new myHandler();
```